# XML/Android: No resource found that matches the given name error

Tags: java, android, xml

I looked up some question posted here, but nothing worked so far, so I figured I'd ask my own. I keep getting the "No resource found that matches the given name(at 'text' with value '@strings/button_name')." error for this .xml file(error is in the last line of the Button tag):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.app2.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/req_input" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@strings/button_name"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my strings.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">App2</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="req_input">Please input the number</string>
    <string name="button_name">Squared</string>

</resources>
```

strings.xml is located in values directory, which is inside res directory. I tried changing `android:text="@strings/button_name"` to `android:text="@+strings/button_name"` but instead of button text saying "Squared" it says "false". All other references to strings.xml are working fine. I'm new to Android programming so please explain as simple as possible.

Comment: It should be `@string` not `@strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `@strings/button_name` to `@string/button_name` and it'll solve your problem!

Comment: Wow. I spent at least half an hour trying to figure out what's wrong, and I only needed to delete one letter. Thank you for your help.